# How can eliminate .svg files that my project doesn't need! Angular-cli - flag-icon-css

Tags: svg, angular-cli

Can you help me! When I import flag-icon-css library in my Angular-cli project and then execute **ng build** in dist folder appears all flags in SVG format(more than 500). I only need two flags! Can I import chosen flags?

[image: dist folder]

Answer (score 0):

You have to alter 4 files, which are inside:

```
node_modules > flag-icon-css
```

On the less folder:

- flag-icon-list.less
- flag-icon-more.less

On the sass folder:

- _flag-icon-list.sass
- _flag-icon-more.sass

On both flag-icon-list files, just remove the flags that you don't want to use.

I also deleted the references in the flag-icon-more.

[flag-icon-css docs](https://github.com/lipis/flag-icon-css)